# Javascript resubmits form in new window with specific dimensions

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, onchange

I have the following form which creates a list of options to a dropdown field. Upon change of the selected value, the script resubmits the form and opens in a new tab. How can I have the form open in a new window with predefined dimensions (width, height)?

```
    <form action="STRcontact_us.asp" method="post" name="frmsubmit" target="new"> 

  <select name="options" onChange="javascript: document.forms['frmsubmit'].submit()"> 

<option value="sales">Select Department</option> 
<option value="Material Handling Components">Material Handling Components</option> 
<option value="Construction Components">Construction Components</option> 
<option value="Track Pad ">Track Pad</option> 
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving the select an ID and add this to the head

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/At5ze/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("sel1").onchange=function() {
    window.open("","newWin","width=400,height=500");
    this.form.submit();
  }
}
```

using

```
<form action="STRcontact_us.asp" method="post" name="frmsubmit" target="newWin"> 

  <select name="options" id="sel1">
```

If IE gives you a hard time we need to change the script a bit

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("sel1").onchange=function() {
    window.open("","newWin","width=400,height=500");
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.forms[0].submit();
    },100);// allow IE to get over the shock of opening a window
  }
}
```

Other thing: no need to have `javascript:` in an event handler

Comment: Hi and thank you for your reply.

Is there anything missing from the code that I have to put on the head? The onchange doesn't open any window.

Comment: Do you have a popup blocker? Also I had a typo. getElements should be getElement

Comment: I did the correction of the getElement and I am trying it on 3 different browsers with no result. No popup blocker enabled.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you wrap the code in `<script>...</script>`? See my fiddle update

Comment: I had misplaced the <script>.
The code works now as expected.

Thank you for all your time and help.